# Is `map` faster than `each`?

Tags: ruby

Is `map` faster at iterating over the array than `each`? Is there speed difference between the two?

- Map

  ```
  result = arr.map {|a| a + 2}
  ```
- Each

  ```
  result = []
  arr.each do |a| 
    result.push(a + 2)
  end
  ```

Comment: I would argue that speed does not matter in this case. Any speed up would come at the cost of less clear code.

Comment: `map` is not faster at iterating, it's faster at building a new array out of an existing one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think yes.

I've tried this test

```
require "benchmark"

n=10000
arr=Array.new(10000,1)
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  #Map
  x.report do
    n.times do
      result = arr.map {|a| a + 2}
    end
  end


  #Each
  x.report do
    n.times do
      result = []
      arr.each do |a|
        result.push(a + 2)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I got this times

```
       user     system      total        real
   5.790000   0.060000   5.850000 (  5.846956)
   8.210000   0.030000   8.240000 (  8.233849)
```

Seems like map it's faster

I saw this video http://confreaks.tv/videos/goruco2015-how-to-performance
she shows many ruby profiles and tools, if you are interested to improve your performance you will find a lot of tips there.

**added**

This is a crazy behavior for me!

```
require "benchmark"

n=10000
arr=Array.new(10000,1)
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  #Map
  x.report do
    n.times do
      result = arr.map {|a| a + 2}
    end
  end
  #Each and push
  x.report do
    n.times do
      result = []
      arr.each do |a|
        result.push(a + 2)
      end
    end
  end

 #Each and <<
  x.report do
    n.times do
      result = []
      arr.each do |a|
        result << (a + 2)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the result

```
       user     system      total        real
   5.880000   0.080000   5.960000 (  5.949504)
   8.160000   0.010000   8.170000 (  8.164736)
   6.630000   0.010000   6.640000 (  6.632686)
```

is the operator "<<" faster than method push? I didn't expect that, I thought that was a kind of alias.

Comment: I ran this a lot of times, and change the order (each at the beginning and then map) and always got the same values.

Answer (score 5):

`each` should be faster than `map` since the former does not modify/create anything while the latter does. But in your code, you are comparing different things. It is `push` that is taking time. Your code is irrelevant from comparing `each` and `map`.

Comment: I was looking for a similar case, our legacy code had a lot of map blocks that didn't actually need to return anything, they were just doing some calculations, so I decided to change them to each. I tested and indeed, if you don't care about the return value, each is faster. And makes more sense when you read it

Answer (score 5):

[This is the source for `each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-each) in MRI v2.2.2:

```
               VALUE
rb_ary_each(VALUE array)
{
    long i;
    volatile VALUE ary = array;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

and [this is the source for `map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
               static VALUE
rb_ary_collect(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;
    VALUE collect;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0, ary_enum_length);
    collect = rb_ary_new2(RARRAY_LEN(ary));
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_ary_push(collect, rb_yield(RARRAY_AREF(ary, i)));
    }
    return collect;
}
```

Notice that `map` and `each` are almost the same (which is to be expected) but `map` also needs to create an array, and then it does a push. Your version of `each` in Ruby is basically doing the same thing, but yours is Ruby, this is C, so there will be extra overhead through recreating the lower level at the higher, and that C is faster than Ruby in general anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not definitive, but indicative:

```
require 'fruity'

def mapit(a)
  a.map {|e| e + 2}.size
end

def eachit(a)
  result = []
  a.each do |e| 
    result.push(e + 2)
  end.size
end

a = Array.new(1_000) { rand 10 }
compare do 
  map    { mapit(a) }
  each   { eachit(a) }
end
  #=> Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 1 second.
  #=> map is faster than each by 2x ± 0.1

a = Array.new(10_000) { rand 10 }
compare do 
  map    { mapit(a) }
  each   { eachit(a) }
end
  #=> Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 1 second.
  #=> map is faster than each by 50.0% ± 10.0%

a = Array.new(100_000) { rand 10 }
compare do 
  map    { mapit(a) }
  each   { eachit(a) }
end
  #=> Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
  #=> map is faster than each by 2x ± 0.1
```

This is an imperfect benchmark of your two methods. Asking whether `each` or `map` is faster only makes sense for very specific comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

I've come upon this three years later, because I wanted to answer the same question that the OP posed under different circumstances. It's clear that if you use `map` and `each` to create a new array, `map` is faster, as the existing answers explain.

However, it seems to me that the real question is whether it is faster to create a new array with some modifications using `map` or make the same modifications to an existing array using `each`. To test this, I modified the benchmark in the accepted answer thus:

```
require "benchmark"

def mapmethod(input)
  input.map(&:reverse)
end

def eachmethod(input)
  input.map(&:reverse!)
end

n=10000
arr=Array.new(10000,'ab')
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  #Map
  x.report do
    n.times do
      mapmethod(arr)
    end
  end

  #Each
  x.report do
    n.times do
      eachmethod(arr)
    end
  end
end
```

And I got this result:

```
   user     system      total        real
27.362799   0.103154  27.465953 ( 28.441034)
15.204973   0.392920  15.597893 ( 15.993965)
```

This seems to me a pretty strong indicator that modifying an existing array is significantly quicker than creating a new one with the same modifications. So, if you don't need a new array, and performance is a priority, I would use `each`. Otherwise, I'd use `map`.

Comment: I got confused, in both, `mapmethod` and `eachmethod` you use `map`, with the difference only on `reverse` versus `reverse!`

Comment: @CrisR Yes, the difference is that `reverse` creates a new array, while `reverse!` modfies the existing one. Ruby has many such methods, where the version with a bang (!) applies the changes directly to the the receiver and the one without returns a new object with the changes applied to it.